# Making Requests Between React Server and Flask Server

Tags: reactjs, http, flask, python-requests, server-side

So I have an application that will have many different microservices that will each run on their own server.  For the frontend, there will be a react server that will hopefully be able to make http requests to all of these different microservices.

My question is how do I configure the urls in order to route them to the different servers? Say the react server is running on localhost:5000 and my microservice is flask and is running on localhost:3000. Currently I'm using axios to make a put request, but everytime it is sending the request to localhost:5000.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably just used a relative url like

```
/mymicroservice/api
```

So Axios assuming it's also on

```
localhost:5000
```

You will need to use absolute URLs for your requests. You should put together a table of URL's that you are going to use, and use a different set when you get to other environments (such as production)